# PHP string length incorrect

Tags: php, string

I am trying to filter an array based on the existence of certain strings. However I am unable to match the string I am looking for, despite knowing it does exist.

See below.

```
 [0]=> string(31) "U T I L I Z A T I O N L I S T"
```

As you can see, the string length is interpreted as 31..? A quick manual count confirms 29 characters including white space. When trying to match this string...

```
if ($value == "U T I L I Z A T I O N L I S T") {
    //do stuff
}
```

Does not work. The string does not match.

What could be the issue? Why does PHP believe the string to contain 31 characters?

Comment: Invisible characters.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois is most likely right. And, given the difference is 2, you are probably dealing with something like `\r\n` at the end of the string. Try pushing the value through [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: Trim didn't seem to work, however preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $value) did the trick. Thanks for the suggestion, definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a way to return the value of the string in raw format? To see where the invisible characters exist etc, for future reference?

Comment: Hm, you could send a `Content-Type: text/plain` header, that should show you just the raw text.

Comment: Seem to have a similar issue when forcing text/plain content, for example another value in the array reads as string(2) " ". Only a single space in the string from what I can determine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple consecutive spaces in your string and html display only one space of consecutive spaces.

Correction:

```
 echo "<pre>$mystring</pre>";
```

This code will display correctly the string

Comment: When echoing with <pre> tags, and forcing the content type to text/plain, I am able to indentify the string as "U T I L I Z A T I O N   L I S T". An extra 2 spaces that were insible without the pre tags. Thanks!

Next up... I have another string in the array which I am still unable to match. Despite <pre> tags and text/plain type, the string still appears as string(2) " ". A single whitespace, recognised as 2. Stripping all whitespace from the string using preg_replace does not seem to allow me to match it, as it did with the UTILIZATION string. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try trim($yourString) to strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of the string

Comment: No luck with trim(), nor pre_replace- string still appears as whitespace and a character count of 2.

Comment: Use `function strhex($string) {
  $hexstr = unpack('H*', $string);
  return array_shift($hexstr);
}` to convert the string to a series of displayable hex bytes... that should help identify the characters

Comment: Try $string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string); to remove some invisible caracters